# automating/triggering clicks on a website

Tags: javascript, html

I have 1000s routine clicks that I have to do on website.

They involve clicking on an option on a drop down menu that pops up after clicking on a name and then repeating this about a dozen times then loading for more names at the bottom of the page and repeating the procedure for 1000s of names

I have basic skills in web development and I am told a JavaScript can be used to automate this clicks but I have never used it to automate actions or trigger clicks on a website

Please help me save time

Comment: Look into automation with tools like Selenium

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to do it with jquery, JavaScript using this technique 
$('button').click();
But the best thing is to use automation software to perform all your tasks on your computer.
This one may help you alot.
https://www.jitbit.com/macro-recorder/

Comment: I had opted for writing the script myself coz the licenses for these automation softwares are out of my budget

Comment: And I use a Mac and both the suggestions are for Windows